# Sharepoint 2010 when adding user to a sharepoint group, no permissions are taken

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am programatically adding a AD user to some SharePoint groups.

```
spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
SPUser lookupUser = spWeb.EnsureUser(username);
if (lookupUser != null)
{
    spGroup.AddUser(lookupUser);
}
spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Have tried running this, as (logged in with the administrator account) and tried running with elevated privileges.

The user is added to the groups as required. The problem is, when I use the SharePoint function "Check Permissions" under "Site Permissions" it shows the user as having no permissions.

Everywhere I look in the internet simply shows the use of the AddUser method. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the WebApplication is using Claims Authentication... if so you probably use the wrong username or there are multiple similar users with different usernames ("i:0#.w|\" and "") -> check /_catalogs/users/simple.aspx. 
Delete the wrong one from the SiteCollection.

Comment: This was the problem. In the different cases of adding and deleting and with the standard sharepoint admin, it was getting mixed up with users with "i:0#.w|" and without.

Thanks @pyranha.

Answer (score 0):

Your group seems to be missing actual permissions to the site. Did you assign the group at least *Read* permisssions for the site? If not the *Check permissions* feature works as expected. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4514484/848859) for code sample for assigning the group some permissions.

If the group has permissions assigned maybe the problem lies in a missing call to `spGroup.Update()` after adding the user to group. Have you tried calling this method?

Comment: The groups have permissions. If I add the users manually to the group using the standard SharePoint function it works. The users get the permissions which the groups have. When I use the above mentioned code, the permissions are not taken. Very strange.

Comment: @PhilPrett Have you tried calling the `spGroup.Update()` method (see my edited answer)?